# Generate XSD with validation form ASP.NET Web API models

Tags: validation, model, xsd, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a ASP.NET Web API project with a few MVC models. Is it possible to generate XSD's from the MVC models?

And, is it possible to keep the validation data annotations in the generated XSD's? If not it would be cool to have basic XSD's generated from the classes I have.

**EDIT**

I found that `xsd.exe -t:[classname] [dllname].dll` generates the XSD for me. My only open question is, how do I keep the validation?